# Create cron job

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, cron

I want to create a cron job that will be launched a file at 2AM Thursdays, Fridays, and Saturdays.

For some reason I get really confused doing that.

Can someone give an example on how to do this?

Comment: Thank you for specifying that by weekend you meant Thursday, Friday and Saturday; I suspect lots of people here would otherwise have interpreted "weekend" as Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Lucky guy, living in a country that has 3-day weekends...

Answer (score 3):

The format of the `cron` table entry is as follows:

```
min hr date month weekday command
```

So, the entry for 2AM on Thu/Fri/Sat would be:

```
0 2 * * 4,5,6 /path/to/command
```

You can also use ranges:

```
0 2 * * 4-6 /path/to/command
```

The weekday field starts with `0` on Sunday (`7` is also Sunday).

Some versions of `cron` will even let you spell it out:

```
0 2 * * Thu-Sat /path/to/command
```

If you want a handy tool that will explain cron table entries to you, [this](http://crontab.guru) site might be pretty helpful.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this is appropriate for a per-user cron file. If this is in a system-wide cron file (typically /etc/cron.\*/\*) you need to prefix the command with the user that the command should be executed as, making the format `min hour day month weekday user command`.

Comment: In addition to Michael's comment above, MOST times /etc/cron.*/* is used by package maintainers for package/program specific stuff.  Of course, you as the sysadmin have the choice of adding other tasks there as well.

Comment: @Xozu Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  If you're happy with the answer, accepting it and maybe even upvoting it is the best way to say "Thank You!" :-)