# Automatic expiration date for UNIX group membership

Tags: linux, rhel, date, group

I want to add user to specific UNIX group only for 6 months. Then I want automatically kick him out of this group and I don't want to expire his username. Which command should I use?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is that you could schedule <s>a [cron job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365444/391847)</s> [an at job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97882/why-do-we-need-the-at-command-in-linux) to run the [command that removes the user from the group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-a-group).

Edit: Based on **telcoM** 's comment

Comment: Actually [an `at` job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97882/258991) might be a better choice, since it's a task that needs to happen just once at a particular future time. Cron jobs are better suited for repeating tasks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Updated answer.